# Unpacking a sequence structure using a `for` loop statement in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I am having a problem understanding why the following cannot be unpacked in the header line of a `for` loop.

Given that:

```
>>> (a,b),c = (1,2),3
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```

Why when I then do this do I receive an error?:

```
for (a,b),c in [(1,2),3]:
...    print(a,b,c)
```

I am aware of how to get it working, as the following gives me the desired result:

```
>>> for (a,b),c in [((1,2),3)]:
...    print(a,b,c)
1 2 3
```

But why is an extra parenthesis enclosing the original object in the header line of the `for` loop required to achieve this output?

Given that any sequence can be unpacked `[(1,2), 3]` is syntactically correct as a list sequence, and should theoretically be able to be assigned to the target variables `(a,b),c`. So why is this not the case and why do I have to enclose the sequence with an additional parenthesis?

Some clarity around this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop is iterating over the list entries, so the first time it tries to assign `(1,2)` to `(a,b),c`, which won't work. Adding the extra parentheses converts `(1,2),3` into a tuple which is a single list entry `((1,2),3)` to assign to `(a,b),c` the first time the `for` loop iterates, which works.

Try:

```
for v in [(1,2),3]:
   print v
```

And you will see that `v` is assigned `(1,2)`, then `3`.